# Next page PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have three pages. When I navigate from page 1 to page 2, everything is ok but when I navigate to page 3 it crashes ( I can't navigate to more than one page )

Here is my code it's same for all three pages

---

```
    def ABC(self):
        self.s= QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_Third()
        self.ui.AB(self.s)
        self.s.show()
```

Note : from Third import Ui_Third  ( Third is name of file , Ui_Third is name of class )

Note 2: Thirdpage To my understanding is a function || the error it crashes ( stop working without any message )

Comment: There is a reason why `ThirdPage` has not the parameter `Dialog2`, which you then call in `Dialog2.hide()` ?

Comment: Dialog3 for page 3, Dialog2 for page 2 , Dialog for page 1
Dialog2.hide() to hide second page after navigate to page 3 when i remove Dialog2.hide() , Dialog.hide() , Dialog 3.hide() it work fine the problem i need to hide page 1 after navigate to page 2

Comment: Do you want to see page 1 and page 3?

Comment: fine, but it seems that `ThirdPage` is trying to access a variable (`Dialog2`) which is not defined. BTW, can you post the error you got ?

Comment: @BoySmile: no one can read this unformated stuff in the comment, pls edit your questions and add them their.

Comment: I re-written the question to be more clear